# why we need write this: :domain => "xxx"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I start to study Rails, and formed such a question:
in

> config.action_mailer.smtp_settings

we have settings:

> :domain         => 'blackrood.com', ( for example )

but i can undersand, why we need this option ( i change it, and nothin change)
tell me plz where we use this option and if i mack site blackrood.com, i must put in

> :domain = >  'blackrood.com'

or

> :domain => 'http://...

or ( in development )

> :domain => 'localhost:3000/blackrood.com'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the domain because the mailer has no other way to determine your domain. That information can only be reliably determined from an http request, which is why controllers and views don't need the domain for URL helpers.

When you specify it, use "domain.com" since this is the only part the mailer will use.